# is there a way to store value of list into a global variable in a function in Python?

Tags: python, list

I tried to make a function that storing an element of list and variable each other.

so I made a code like this:

```
reg = ['0','1','2','3']
var = 25


def LD(d,t):
    reg[d]=t
    
def ST(d,t):
    t=reg[d]
```

I tried this code, and LD function worked correctly,
but ST function did not work

```
LD(2,var) # reg changed to ['0', '1', 25, '3']
ST(0,var) # var is still 25
```

Is this problem related to call by reference/value?

How can I store a value of an element in list into a variable?

Comment: Passing `var` as a parameter simply makes its value available to the function; it doesn't give the function any way to assign a new value to the variable.  The way you get a value out of a function is to `return` it, and have the caller assign the result of the call.

Comment: You aren't assigning to `reg` in `LD`; you are really calling a method on the global variable, i.e. `reg.__setitem__(d, t)`. In `ST`, you are assigning to a *local* variable `t`. You'll want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Answer (score 0):

Like @jasonharper had said "Passing var as a parameter simply makes its value available to the function". What you need is to return the new value in the function and store that returned value in `var` (outside the function).

```
reg = ['0','1','2','3']
var = 25


def LD(d,t):
    reg[d]=t
    
def ST(d,t):
    #return what *var* should be 
    return reg[d]
    
LD(2,var) # reg changed to ['0', '1', 25, '3']
#store returned value in *var*
var = ST(0,var)
```